# Is there any way to take nearest location value from an elasticsearch index?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have 2 elasticsearch index, one with userlocation and another "locationvalues"

```
"userlocation" : {
"aliases" : { },
"mappings" : {
  "properties" : {
    "_class" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "email" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "latitude" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "longitude" : {
      "type" : "float"
    },
    "timestamp" : {
      "type" : "long"
    }
  }
},

    {
  "locationvalues" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "LocationLat" : {
          "type" : "double"
        },
        "LocationLong" : {
          "type" : "double"
        },
        "Source" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "TimeStamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "epoch_millis"
        },
        "Value" : {
          "type" : "double"
        }
      }
    },
```

Is there anyway to bring from locationvalues just the nearest location from userlocation, on coresponding timestamp (+- 10 minutes)? I must to specify that the timestamp in the userlocation has different values compared to the one in the locationvalue.

Timestamp have format epoch UNIX milliseconds!
locationvalues have more than 100k elements/month and userlocation more than 5000.

Comment: Can you please refine your question with some additional details? How do you plan to query, one query per userlocation? What version of the Elasticstack are you using? How do you index your data? (Your current mappings don‘t allow for queries as intended. Geo coordinates and timestamps need to be changed). I‘m waiting for your input first and then answer your question

Comment: I need to aproximate pollution data based on userlocation. In "locationvalues" i have pollution data and, for every value in "userlocation" i need to take nearest values from "userlocation". I use Elasticstack 7.10.1 and i cant modify Geo coordinates and Timestamp because i just read data. Thank you, @DanielSchneiter!

Answer (score 1):

It seems as you rather want to pull a report than the result of a single Elasticsearch query. What you want to achieve is not possible with a single query. You would need to write a client application that first queries for all existing "user locations" and then submit a query for every single "user location" to the location values index.

Elasticsearch can calculate the distance between geo-locations and also factor sort results based on geo-distance. Elasticsearch also supports data-math to easily query for date ranges such as "within 10 minutes", etc.

But Elasticsearch can only do so if the data is stored in the proper format. Independent to whom created the Elasticsearch index that mapping does not look ideal. Longitude and Latitude information should not be stored as 2 float fields, but rather as a [geo_point](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html#geo-point) field.

In order to support date_range queries you need to store timestamps as proper timestamps (and not as long). Via the [format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#mapping-date-format) parameter you can control the valid date/time-formats you're planning to send to Elasticsearch (can be multiple format strings!). Elasticsearch will then not just use this information to validate the timestamps but also to properly convert them into the internally used epoch_millis representation for storing.

Even if you can't change any of the existing mappings to maintain backward compatibility, you could consider adding new "multi-fields" to your mapping to ensure your data being stored in the proper format. But you would need to get write privileges (along with the privilege to execute an _update_by_query-request) to get your index mappings fixed first.